# How to extract main text from website and exclude archive and link to other webpage using JSOUP

Tags: java, jsoup

I only know how to extract main text and exclude the comment but fail to exclude the archive and link to other webpage.

This is my code:

```
package CrawlerMain;

import java.io.IOException;
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Node;

public class MainFour {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.papagomo.com").get();
        //get text only
        removeComments(doc); 
        String text = doc.body().text();
        System.out.println(text);
    }

    private static void removeComments(Node node) {
        int i = 0;
        while (i < node.childNodes().size()) {
            Node child = node.childNode(i);
            if (child.nodeName().equals("#comment"))
                child.remove();
            else {
                removeComments(child);
                i++;
            }
        } //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }

}
```

Comment: Please give us some more informations about your problem / error.

Comment: This code will extract text and ignore text in comment box. However it is also extract text in the archive box and also time and the date entry posted in that particular website. The problem here is I don't know how to extract the main text only and ignore everything.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an example, but it's not complete yet. You have to add some filtering to remove everything you don't want:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.papagomo.com").get();


for( Element element : doc.select("div") ) // Select only 'div' tags
{
    final String ownText = element.ownText(); // Own text of this element

    if( ownText.isEmpty() )
    {
        continue; // Skip empty tags
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println(ownText); // Output to see the result
    }
}
```

Comment: If your question is answered, please accept the answer (http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask)